# Zuul Routing on Root Path

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I want to config zuul to route request to root `/` to a home page. I tried:

```
root:
  path: /
  url: http://hostname/home/index.jsp
```

and

```
root:
  path: /**
  url: http://hostname/home/index.jsp
```

But neither of them works. I just got a 404 NOT FOUND. I think the path match config should be similar to those with contexts, such as `/service/**`, but it's not.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I have done to make this work.

Within Zuul -> controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest() {
    return "forward:/ux/";
}
```

Zuul Properties:

```
zuul:
  addProxyHeaders: true
  routes:
    example-ux:
      path: /ux/**
      stripPrefix: false
```

Within example-ux Service properties:

```
server:
  servlet-path: /*
  context-path: /ux
```

This configuration also solves the problem of static resources resolution.  i.e. `/static/css` `static/js` etc...

Comment: Note: This is based on using Eureka for Service Discovery

Comment: When I did it, it just returned the string "forward:/ux/" to my browser. I think it's because there's no view named "/ux/" defined in the container. How did you define that? Also, in your second config, I suppose you missed `serviceId` or `url`? Otherwise how do you do routing. Thanks.

Comment: Within the example-ux service you still need either an index.html or index controller to render the ui.  the `serviceId` or `url` is not required.

Comment: I still cannot get it work. I don't quite understand if you don't specify url or serviceId, how would zuul know the location of your example-ux service? Where would it forward the request to?

Comment: I have the target app, to which zuul routes, working. But `return "forward:/ux/";` in zuul still just returns me a string. I think `forward` keyword needs to work with a controller with the same name (`/ui` in this case) in zuul.

Comment: @ccit-spence : Its failing on static resources for me. How did you reference static resources within your ux app. did you give the full path like ux/static/js/xxxx.js or did you give it relative to the app like static/js/xxx.js

Comment: @PavanSandeep Not sure exactly your setup.  Static in Spring Boot usually the word static is dropped.  `ux/js/xxxx.js`

Comment: @ccit-spence : Understood, my point is, when you drop the client resources in the static folder of Spring boot, lets say index.html and I'm referencing /js/app.js. When it is routed through zuul, it's not adding the ux/js/app.js while routing, however, it is routing to the index page in ux app.

Comment: @PavanSandeep Ah, My approach was to put the static files on Zuul.