# Spring Cloud: default redirecting from Gateway to UI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I'm new to microservices and Spring Boot. I have a few Spring Cloud microservices with a Zuul gateway running on port 8080.

```
   browser
      |
      |
    gateway   (:8080)
     /   \
    /     \
   /       \
resource   UI (:8090)
```

There is a UI microservice on port 8090, which has a controller with a method inside, returning index.html.

I configured Zuul routing like this for UI (I'm using Eureka too):

```
zuul:
  routes:
    ui:
      path: /ui/**
      serviceId: myproject.service.ui
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

If I call `http://localhost:8080/ui/` everything works fine and I see rendering of my index.html.

Is it possible to configure Spring Cloud in some way to make the following flow work: calling `http://localhost:8080/` redirects us to controller of UI microservice, which returns index.html?

So the idea is to open UI from the root of my site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986500/zuul-routing-on-root-path

Comment: @pan, thank you very much. Very interesting solution, but, as I understood, it can't serve **static** files like **js** or **css**. Unfortunately, it can only return `index.html`. If it wants to load some static content, redirect mechanism for some reason doesn't work, and browser gets 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I've made my code work! Thanks to @pan for mentioning [Zuul Routing on Root Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38986985/3399581) question and @RzvRazvan for revealing about how Zuul routing works.

I've just added **controller** to Zuul routed Gateway microservice with one endpoint to redirect from root `http://localhost:8080/` to `http://localhost:8080/ui/`:

```
@Controller
public class GateController {    
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/ui/";
    }    
}
```

**Zuul** properties for redirecting from **Gateway microservice** on port **8080** as `http://localhost:8080/ui/` to **UI microservice**, which implemented as a separate Spring Boot application on port **8090** as `http://localhost:8090/ui/`:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    ui:
      path: /ui/**
      serviceId: myproject.service.ui
      stripPrefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

UI microservice's properties:

```
server:
  port: 8090
  servlet:
     contextPath: /ui
```

Eventually, this call `http://localhost:8080/` redirects us to controller of UI microservice, which returns view `index.html`:

```
@Controller
public class UiController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

---

Actually, I had another problem with rendering static content in such architecture, but it was connected with configuration of my front-end, which I develop using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) framework. I will describe it here in a few sentences, in case it might be helpful for someone.

I have the following folders structure of UI microservice:

```
myproject.service.ui
    └───src/main/resources
        └───public
            |───static
            |    ├───css
            |    └───js
            └───index.html
```

All content of `public` folder is generated by `npm run build` task from **webpack** and **vue.js**. First time, I called my `http://localhost:8080/` I got **200 OK** for `index.html` and **404** for all other static resources, because they was called like this:

```
http:\\localhost:8080\static\js\some.js
```

So it was configured wrong public path for static assets in webpack. I changed it in `config\index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  build: {
    ...
    assetsPublicPath: '/ui/',
    ...
  }
...
}
```

And static assets became to be called properly. e.g.:

```
http:\\localhost:8080\ui\static\js\some.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have on Zuul the UI(front-end) you can add the static content in *resources/static* folder(html, css and js files). On this way your proxy is able to render the index.html (of course you must have an index.html in static folder). O this way on `http://localhost:8080` the proxy will render index.html; also you can have another paths but all these path are managed by index.html)

About routing, the Zuul only redirect the http request. *http://localhost:8080/ui/*. On `8080` is running the proxy (Zuul) BUT `/ui` is the context path of resource server. Se when you make a call on this path *http://localhost:8080/ui/* the proxy will redirect to resource server and will actually  make a request to *http://localhost:8090/ui/*

It is a difference between browser path and http request path. The browser path is managed by index.html and the http request is managed by Zuul. I don't know if I was explicit enough.

One more thing... You can have the same path (`/ui`) on http request and index.html and when your browser will access the *http://localhost:8080/ui/* a .js file with http request method will make an http request to *http://localhost:8080/ui/*  and then will be redirected to *http://localhost:8090/ui/* and the response from the resource server will be rendered on the page from *http://localhost:8080/ui/*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, it is impossible to store static content inside UI microservice, according to my architecture, and to try to get it by calling `http://localhost:8080/ui`, isn't it? 

By the way, when I call `http://localhost:8090/ui/` I also can't render whole UI because of all static resources show 404, except `index.html`

Comment: When You make a call at http://localhost:8090/ui/ you will receive data (json for example) from UI server; when you make a call at http://localhost:8080/ui/  actually you make a call at Zuul which redirect the request at UI server ( on port 8090). So, 1st question is : where do you make the call at port 8080? using a method in JavaScript file? 2nd question is : where do you store the static content? Do you have a 2nd server such as node.js ? Your details in your question are very vague... Also you said that you can open index.html but on other u receive 404;aread about WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: **1.** For example, I called `http://localhost:8080/ui/` from the browser, so Zuul redirected me to UI microservice, which implemented as separate Spring Boot application. **2.** So I store all static content inside `src/main/resources/public/static` folder. When I called UI, browser showed me (in Chrome console) that it was unable to get static content. It tried to get static from e.g. `http://localhost:8080/static/...` and got 404. Fortunately, I have fixed this and now everything seems work fine!